# iframe w3 with properties

Tags: iframe, w3c-validation

So I've been working with a webpage. We have iframes to display our sponsor images, we need &s in the url stack to make sure the image shows up correctly. However w3 says that this isn't correct saying "This is usually a cascading error caused by a an undefined entity reference or use of an unencoded ampersand (&) in an URL or body text. See the previous message for further details."

One of our sponsor codes iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe id="cm_sponsor" name="sponsors" src="http://members.stcharleschamber.com/directory/jsp/Sponsors.jsp?ccid=423&context=102&catgid=&rotate=1&maxAds=99" width="210" height="90"></iframe>
```

Can anyone help with ampersands and how it would look like?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ampersands (`&`) in the URL with `&amp;`.

```
<iframe id="cm_sponsor" name="sponsors" src="http://members.stcharleschamber.com/directory/jsp/Sponsors.jsp?ccid=423&amp;context=102&amp;catgid=&amp;rotate=1&amp;maxAds=99" width="210" height="90"></iframe>
```